# Oracle with .Net without refcursor

Tags: oracle, dataset, ref-cursor

I have a query regarding refcursor. I am using refcursor as out parameter in oracle stored procedure. I have written a simple select query using cursors and return it as dataset to the calling function. Is it possible not to use refcursor and fill the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query directly in .NET and send it to the database. Just set command property "CommandType" accordingly.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your prompt reply. I have a requirement that i should not use inline query